# Parsing json by using Gson.fromJson() method into class< T > model is not working

Tags: java, android, json, types, gson

My problem is, I can't parse json by using Gson.fromJson() method into class< T > model.

In my **PageOutput.java**

```
public class PageOutput<T> {

      @SerializedName("TotalItemCount")
      public int totalItemCount;

      @SerializedName("Items")
      private T[] items;

      public final T[] getItems() {
          return items;
      }
}
```

In **Property.java**

```
public class Property {
   @SerializedName("Id")
   public String id;

   @SerializedName("Title")
   public String title;

   @SerializedName("Price")
   public BigDecimal price;
    ....
}
```

In **Main.java**,

```
PageOutput<Property>  output = new Gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<PageOutput<Property>>(){}.getType());
```

When project is compiled, I get null in Items.

But when I use

```
PageOutput<Property>  output = new Gson.fromJson(jsonString, PageOutput.class);
```

I will get the result in generic object  type for T[] items, by the meantime I should get **Property** type. (Line 18)

```
output = {com.myapp.PageOutput@830048974608}
items = {java.lang.Object[17]@830048616120} //Line 18
[0] = {com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap@830048777632} size = 16
[1] = {com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$Node@830047149712}"Id" -> "2936918.0"
[2] = {com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$Node@830047452528}"Title" -> "Valdor, Penang"
[3] = {com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$Node@830047985896}"Price" -> "7.5698E9"
```

And when I cast this object,

```
Property[] properties = output.getItems(); //Return error
```

I will get error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.myapp.model.Property[]
```

How can I solve the problem? Please help and thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the right way to parse it

```
PageOutput<Property>  output = new Gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<PageOutput<Property>>(){}.getType());
```

and getting null at items means that you need to check your json string and how it was built

Comment: Yes I have tried this method (mentioned in my question), and I've checked my json in jsonParser, and it is not broken.

Comment: Try to build the json string as follow
            Type type = new TypeToken<PageOutput<Property>>() {
            }.getType();

            String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(pageOutputObject, type);

Comment: I have mis-import the Type framework. Seems to be 'import java.lang.reflect.Type;'. Solved. Thank you for everyone who gave answers on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
items= output.getItems();

Property[] properties = itmes.toArray(new Property[items.size()]);
```

Comment: Cannot resolve 'toArray' method. I've import java.util.ArrayList; I think it's not ArrayList type. It's a generic type...

Comment: I will try to cast this generic array object into List, and convert it into array-typed object. Will update this post later.