# Gson parse class with generic item

Tags: java, android, gson

I have base class WebAnswer,

```
public class WebAnswer<T> {

private int id;
private T result;
private ErrorModel error;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public T getResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(T result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public ErrorModel getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(ErrorModel error) {
    this.error = error;
}
}
```

and inherited class RequestAnsModel

```
public class RequestAnsModel extends WebAnswer<RequestModel> {

}
```

I need to deserialize JSON object with Gson, in code I do it like this:

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        WebAnswer<RequestModel> data = new WebAnswer<RequestModel>();
        data = gson.fromJson(response.toString(),data.getClass());
```

and in Field result I get array of objects com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$Node@. But when I do something like this

```
 WebAnswer<RequestModel> data = new RequestAnsModel();
```

I get correct model where result is object of RequestModel. Are there any ways to desirialize in gson somthing like this correct with Generic without create inherited class?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818617/parsing-json-by-using-gson-fromjson-method-into-class-t-model-is-not-workin

Comment: @SuhasB TypeToken will work in case new TypeToken<WebAnswer<RequestModel>>(){}.getType(), but will not work in this case new TypeToken<WebAnswer<T>>(){}.getType()

Answer (score 3):

You should use TypeToken like in the code below:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Type type = new TypeToken<WebAnswer<RequestModel>>() {
}.getType()

WebAnswer<RequestModel> data = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), type);
```